# Weird Behavour in Skforcast

Tags: time-series, xgboost

I applied XGBoost to forcast a univariante time series dataset, the first time I created my own lags features manually:

```
lags = 365 #Number of lags to include
for i in range(1, lags + 1):
    df[f'OT_lag_{i}'] = df['OT'].shift(i).copy()
```

then Trained the XGboost and calculated the MSE on the test set:

```
# Split data into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8) # 80% train, 20% test
train_data, test_data = df.iloc[:train_size].copy(),df.iloc[train_size:].copy() 

model_xgb = xgb.XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror',random_state = 123)

# Fit model
model_xgb.fit(train_data.drop([ 'OT'], axis=1), train_data['OT'])

# Forecast test values
forecast_test = model_xgb.predict(test_data.drop(['OT'], axis=1))
```

I got a 0.4 MSE and this visualization of the predictions:

[image]

I tried to use the skForecast built in *ForecasterAutoreg* and intilizing an XGboost with the same parameters (random state and number of lags) and I got this really weird and bad predictions (MSE = 5 when it was 0.4) on my test set:

```
 forecaster = ForecasterAutoreg(
    regressor = DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state = 1),
    lags = 400)


# Fit model
forecaster.fit(y=train_data)

# Forecast test values
predictions = forecaster.predict(steps= len(test_data))
```

[image]

Comment: The first plot strikes me as too good to be true, while the second looks like maybe at 400 steps it stops doing anything, maybe because it's not using earlier predictions as its lagged features after going 400 steps out from training data?  But I'm not familiar with the package in question.

Comment: @BenReiniger, yes you are absolutly right. I had a train data leak in the first code. the 400 step was just a typo since I run them both on 365 lags.